# Jackson Json generating a space after new line

Tags: java, json, jackson

Here goes my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(new File("test.json"), JsonEncoding.UTF8);

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            jGenerator.writeStartObject(); // {
            jGenerator.writeStringField("name" , "test");
            jGenerator.writeEndObject();   // }
            jGenerator.writeRaw('\n');     // creates new line
        }

        jGenerator.close();

        System.out.println("File Generated");
    }

}
```

After running this when i look into the generated file , it has a space just before each new record .. Is there a way to remove this space while generating the file itself??

Sample Output

```
{"name":"test"}  
 {"name":"test"}  
 {"name":"test"}  
 {"name":"test"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use next [PrettyPrinter](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter.html)

```
   new MinimalPrettyPrinter("");
```

your code will looks like

```
   JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
   JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(new File("test.json"), JsonEncoding.UTF8);
   jGenerator.setPrettyPrinter(new MinimalPrettyPrinter("")); 
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
       jGenerator.writeStartObject();
       jGenerator.writeStringField("name" , "test");
       jGenerator.writeEndObject();
       jGenerator.writeRaw('\n');
    }
    jGenerator.close();
```

Comment: even better: `jGenerator.setPrettyPrinter(new MinimalPrettyPrinter("\n"));` and you can remove writeRaw from the code...